# Delete multiple lines with text and curly braces

Tags: sed, awk

I have a multiple files that contains something like:

```
this is a test1
 {
test 123
test 456
test 789
}

this is a test2
 {
test 123
test 456
test 789
}

this is a test3
 {
test 123
test 456
test 789
}
```

Need to delete a section:

```
this is a test2
 {
test 123
test 456
test 789
}
```

lines between braces may be a different (less or more lines)
I've tried something like :

```
sed -i 's|This is a test2 *.* !}||g' *
```

and

```
sed -i 's|This is a test2, !}||g' *
```

but no success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about

```
sed -e '/this is a test2/,/}/d'
```

which basically

- `-e` tell sed to use next pattern
- `/this is a test2/,/}/` select line between `this is a test2` and `}`
- `d` delete it

Usage

```
 sed -e '/this is a test2/,/}/d' A > B
```

- apply sed from A file into B

  ```
  sed -i  -e '/this is a test2/,/}/d' A
  ```
- edit directly into A

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach with awk:

```
awk '/test2/,/^}/{next}1' file > newfile
```

(Has the disadvantage of leaving a blank line, which may not be acceptable...)

Comment: this is useful too, but the solution of the Archemar is better for multiple files. Thanks a lot